# Who Are Some Literary Agents That Accept Christian Fantasy Novels?

Tags: fantasy, agent

I have about four thoroughly reviewed novels that are technically Christian fantasy novels. I am looking for an agent, a literary agents, that is open to representing these kinds of books. I have realized that agents who represent secular fantasies don't like reading religious works, even if those religious works are crossover novels. Does anyone know any agents that represent my genre? I'd appreciate the help.